# Learning High School Geometry in Ten Days

Tags: geometry, self-learning

I would like to attempt this, as I want to place out of geometry next year. It is imperative that I do it now. How should I go about doing this?

I have a copy of [*Elementary Geometry for College Students, 6th Edition*](https://www.cengage.com/c/elementary-geometry-for-college-students-6e-alexander) by Dan Alexander and Geralyn Koeberlein.

Comment: I am curious. Why would you like to place out of geometry?

Comment: Why stop with geometry? At this pace you'll be ready for graduate school in math by March or so.

Comment: Do you know squares are rectangles? Does it say so in your book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Read the text and work the homework problems.
2. Design a self study plan based on the time you have available (80-100 hours).  I'm not sure that is enough, would estimate 180 needed if this is material you have never seen before.  But design a plan (hours per section and such) and see how it goes.
3. Use a notebook or compiled looseleaf.  Develop some system (sections of notebook or icons at top of page to differentiate self notes, homework, questions (with room for answers!), and self tests.

3.5. Use the section for questions to "parking lot" things you don't understand as you go.  You can then refer these to the Internet or someone (parent?  older student?)  But I suspect many of them you will figure out yourself.  But still is good discipline to work through as you teach yourself, to write things down you have questions and then put the resolution down (even if it is you after working a few problems or reading next section).

4. For time efficiency, I would attempt the HW problems that have answers in the back and/or reserve some for self testing.  Make sure you actually WORK the problems.  NOT say "oh I get it".  But really work problems.  And really test yourself.  Anything you get wrong on a HW problem or self test has to be reworked (even if a silly mistake).
5. Check the book suitability.  You say you want high school geometry but that is some random college book.  Is the material fitting your needs?  Can you check with an upperclassman what book they use or even borrow it for the holidays?

---

This would be an easier question to answer if you did a little more work yourself in terms of devising an initial plan, describing it and then asking for feedback.  Just showing up with a terse question does not show much investment by you.  And makes it harder to advise you on specifics.

Finally, this site is full of community college instructors who love real analysis.  Not sure they can really advise you.  Talking to a HS math teacher (maybe look for a good blog or such) would do more for you.

Comment: +1 Nice answer focusing on planning. However, I'm not sure the given 10 days is time enough for really working homework. This may be heresy, but given the time constraint, I'm not sure any other option exists than reading the exercises and saying "oh I get it" (or not).